# How to search only in several fragments from ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

Recently I've added a tool for searching inside fragments. Some fragments have ListViews, so when a user types a search text, a ListView filters rows.
This is done with ActionBar after this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/).

I attached listeners from several fragments to a MainActivity, so when a user types a text at the top of the screen, it filters rows in a fragment. But in other fragments there is no need to search for anything, so a magnifying glass should be hidden.

However a **magnifier** is drawn at **every screen**. I also tried to not show it in activity and draw only in a fragment with this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_invitro, menu);
    menu.clear();
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.clearFocus();

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

But a magnifier stays in other fragments, also it is possible to type a text at the top.

Is there a correct way to show a magnifier only in some fragments?

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer at another forum.

In MainActivity:

```
boolean isVisible;
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(isVisible);
    return true;
}
```

To update an ActionBar it should be called so:

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```